# Java application updating itself on Windows Vista and higher

Tags: java, windows, deployment, upgrade, updating

long time lurker and finally a member here. I have a java application that I am getting ready to release to the public for Windows/OSX/Linux but I am running into problems related to permissions on Windows Vista and higher.

Basically the application installs to the standard c:\Program Files (configurable within the installer) which is great and my application data is stored in the users respective application data folder.

Now here is the part I am struggling with. My application (like most) has the ability to check for updates and update itself. The update process performs the following steps;

1. Download update
2. Backup current application files (ones stored under c:\Program Files....)
3. Unzip update over top of current application files
4. Clean up (deletes update archive etc)
5. Restart main application

There in lies the problem. In order to allow the update process to change its own files, I need to grant the JAR with administrative privileges; this seems crazy. Is there no way to install a java application on these operating systems that are allowed to change their own files by default? Obviously not installing the application into the "Program Files" directory works perfectly fine - but most people install files into these directories (since that is their purpose).

I've been trying to figure out a good solution to this problem for well over a week now but alas I keep coming up empty handed. I am hoping someone here who has experience deploying on these OS' can shed some light on the topic.

Additional information:

- Application structure is an executable jar, with a lib folder of jars, an updater executable jar with a lib folder
- JWS is insufficient with my needs
- This is a problem only on Windows Vista and higher, Windows XP works great because it doesn't have the UAC mechanism
- Application prompts the user that an upgrade is available and what the upgrade contains.

Maybe I am going about this all wrong? I cannot be the first one coming into this problem, there are millions of applications deployed to Windows.

Thank you for your help and suggestions.

Comment: Who, in their right mind, would allow some program to "self update" without requesting permissions (and perhaps validating that the update is not pernicious)?  You might look at "msi packaging" your application, periodically checking for update, and informing user to run an update process.

Comment: Sorry I should have stated the application prompts the user as to whether or not they want to accept the upgrade which also tells them what is available in the new version. It is not a silent upgrade.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is **NO**. **NO** your application cannot change its own files without the correct privileges.

For anyone else that stumbles on this topic here is additional information;

- If you want to write to system files (such as c:\Program Files) you MUST prompt for elevated privileges from the UAC if your application is not already running with admin privileges.
- if your application installs for only the specific user, an alternative may be to install your application only to the specific users local files and therefore be updatable.

**Solution?**
Since my application while running doesn't require elevated privileges, I run the application the standard way, but if an update is available, I prompt the user for elevated permissions. My application calls an external jar (or exe in Windows case) that handles the upgrade, so all I had to do in the end was add the correct Manifest to the upgrade.exe and viola.